# Unable to turn on the EV3

Tags: ev3

I just can not turn on the EV3 with the SD card. I only turned on it twice.
The EV3 stops at [-leJOS EV3] UI and does not go to the next step.

I charged the battery, reinstalled the software inside of the SD card, changed the EV3 for one time, reset the EV3, but I still cannot turn it on.

I can only turn it on without the SD card.

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Have you tried reformatting the SD? It should only contain a single FAT32 partition. Also check it's not a SDXC card, as they are not supported

Comment: Have you looked at the [leJOS EV3 forum](http://www.lejos.org/forum/)? This question gets asked (and answered) there on an almost daily basis.

Comment: This is most likely because of a bad flashing software or  or a bad SD card. But I'm not really certain, as I don't know much about this sort of thing.